# PHP PDO Prepared Statement Query not substituting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a short segment of PHP code:

```
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stm->execute($params);
```

$params is the following

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "why"
}
```

However, the $sql being sent to MySQL still contains a question mark according to the MySQL logs:

```
1 Query SELECT a.* FROM article a
LEFT JOIN article_links al on a.id = al.from_article_id
WHERE al.to_article = '?'
```

Is there something else I'm missing for substitution?

Comment: Does `$sql` have single quotes around the question mark? If so, remove them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have the single quotes around the question mark:

```
SELECT a.* FROM article a
LEFT JOIN article_links al on a.id = al.from_article_id
WHERE al.to_article = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This raises the question though, how does PHP know if I want quotes in my SQL query or not?  For example, in this case, to_article is a varchar, but what if it were an int?

Comment: If you want to define the types of your parameters, use `bindParam`, which you can specify the data types for every parameters. See here for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php, if you need an example let us know! :)

Comment: Should be worth noting that, even if you put quotes around an int, it doesn't matter to MySQL, and that PDO does some magic in the background

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is true:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.* FROM article a LEFT JOIN article_links al on a.id = al.from_article_id WHERE al.to_article = '?'"
```

The question mark should not be surrounded by quotes--this means it's a string instead of a parameter placeholder.  Use just `al.to_article = ?`.

Comment: Thank you.  As I asked above, how can I specify between a string placeholder and an int?

Comment: You don't usually need to. If you want to, you do it at bind-time, not prepare-time. E.g. `$preparedstatement->bindValue($param, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT)`. Default is `PDO::PARAM_STR`